# HTML with sub and sub-sub bullets not showing properly

Tags: android, html, textview

Consider this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some bullet point text.</li>
    <li>Another bullet point:</li>
        <ul>
            <li>A Sub Bullet point of the above.</li>
                  <ul>
                       <li>A Sub sub bullet point.</li>
                 </ul>
            <li>The second sub bullet point.</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

I'm loading this into a TextView in MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val someText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.someTextView)
    val url = "<ul>\n" +
            "    <li>Some bullet point text.</li>\n" +
            "    <li>Another bullet point:</li>\n" +
            "        <ul>\n" +
            "            <li>A Sub Bullet point of the above.</li>\n" +
            "                  <ul>\n" +
            "                       <li>A Sub sub bullet point.</li>\n" +
            "                 </ul>\n" +
            "            <li>The second sub bullet point.</li>\n" +
            "        </ul>\n" +
            "</ul>\n"
    someText.text = Html.fromHtml(url, Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE)
}
```

Nothing special with the activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/someTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Expected (Sub, Sub-sub bullet points):
[image]

Actual (no sub and sub-sub bullets AND indenting is wrong):
[image]

1. I've [tried this library](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview) but it has the same problems.
2. Another solution would be to convert the  tags to "\u25CF" and sub-sub bullets to "\u25CB" (or BulletSpan) and use JSoup for the ordering. But this feels like a lot of work for a standard HTML text.
3. I've tried [MyTagHandler](https://bitbucket.org/Kuitsi/android-textview-html-list/) but the same problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Consider using a WebView, for showing HTML contents. `Html.fromHtml()` is not only **very limited**, but also **deprecated**.

Comment: Then my markup is gone, so no. And the textView.text = Html.fromHtml(text, Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE) is not deprecated.

Comment: `Html.fromHtml()` has been deprecated in Nougat+. Why do you say that your markup is gone? A WebView is perfect for that!

Comment: I'm gonna try this solution https://www.hidroh.com/2016/02/27/richtext-textview-versus-webview/ since fromHtml() doesn't support <ul>. But this is a lot more code: CSS style sheet etc.

Comment: You don't need CSS at all. The base HTML style is the same you would use for a TextView. But it's ***fully*** processed instead of ***partially***. Actually, I fail to see why can't you use your existing HTML (after clearing it from all the useless `\n`).

Comment: I'm using a Custom TextView with different fonts, that's why I prefer to keep using a TextView. WebView looks different because of this. The code in the link above allows me to edit the look and feel of the webview but creates a new problem, white spaces on left and top side...

Comment: Nothing that you can't handle via HTML. A TextView is simply **not the proper view** to display HTML. At least, when we do have a specialized View for that.

Answer (score 0):

***ul*** and ***li*** tags are not supported by ***Html.fromHtml()*** method. There is an open issue in Google Issue Tracker about [these missing tag supports](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36917758) and about the [supported tags not listen](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75982733) on ***Html.fromHtml()*** method's documentation.

But, I think [BulletSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Or maybe this: [HtmlTagHandler](https://gist.github.com/vincent1086/1ca4df897efcf9bc0a4bda771af5636a)